# Função no javascript

Tags: javascript

Colegas.

Tenho um arquivo chamado somar.js do qual estou chamando no index da página dessa forma:

```
 <script src="js/somar.js"></script>
```

O arquivo existe e está corretamente dentro da pasta no servidor, porém quando coloco o comando abaixo no arquivo somar.js:

```
function soma(){
    alert('OK...vamos continuar');
.......
```

Parece não funcionar. Estou chamando esse arquivo da seguinte forma na página index:

```
<select name="QtdAcomodacaoS" id="QtdAcomodacaoSingle" class="form-control" style="width:130px" onchange="soma()">
```

Será que por estar usando o bootstrap, pode estar gerando algum conflito? Coloquei antes do body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especifica o tipo de arquivo como `text/javascript`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/somar.js"></script>
```

E coloque antes de fechar a tag `</body>`.

Um exemplo usando o `<select>`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Comment: Obrigado Diego. Funcionou.